# Serve static assets to AWS s3 with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, sinatra, assets

Has anyone had any experience in serving assets to AWS S3 in a Sinatra app. I have installed the gem

```
asset_sync
```

as per the instructions here https://github.com/ejholmes/asset-sync-sinatra

When i run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

i get this error message in the console

```
cannot load such file -- asset_sync
```

This is my setup

Gemfile

```
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'pony'
gem 'sinatra-flash'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'activesupport', require: 'active_support'
gem 'asset_sync', git: 'git://github.com/ejholmes/asset_sync.git', branch: 'sinatra'
```

config.rb

```
module MyConfig

def config
 environment = ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
 YAML.load_file("./config/config.yml")[environment]
end
end
```

config.yml

```
development:
 aws_access_key: = 'myaccesskey'
 aws_secret_key: = 'mysecretkey'
 fog_directory: = 'applecatering'
```

Rakefile

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'asset_sync'
require './config/config.rb'
include MyConfig

AssetSync.configure do |con|
 con.fog_provider = 'AWS'
 con.fog_region = 'eu-west-1'
 con.fog_directory = config['fog_directory']
 con.aws_access_key_id = config['aws_access_key']
 con.aws_secret_access_key = config['aws_secret_key']
 con.prefix = "assets"
 con.public_path = Pathname("./public")
end

namespace :assets do
 desc "Precompile assets"
 task :precompile do
AssetSync.sync
end
end
```

First time trying this, can anyone see what I am doing wrong, am i missing something or not understanding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your `Rakefile` is including the `Gemfile`.

Try adding this to the top of your `Rakefile`,

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)
```

And try running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

**EDIT:**

Also, maybe drop the `require 'asset_sync'` from the `Rakefile`. `Bundler.require(:default)` should `require` the contents of the `Gemfile`

Comment: ah thank you, now it seems i have an issue with my bucket name, though i thought it complied with their rules

Comment: actual error message fog: the specified s3 bucket name(= 'applecatering') is not a valid dns name, which will negatively impact performance.

Comment: Your bucket name seems to be set to `= 'applecatering'`. Try getting rid of the `=` and quotes around `applecatering` in the place the bucket ENV setting is defined.

Comment: Im loading from a yml file like so fog_directory: = 'applecatering', is it safe to declare this in my rakefile, so if people can see my bucketname in say my github repo, would this cause any security concerns?

Comment: Set this in your YAML file `fog_directory: applecatering` instead.

Comment: hah, i just got to that by process of elimination, didnt realise i could set the variable without any =   thank you for your help

Comment: ive marked answer as correct, still not working but scope of answer was correct, now i get Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)

Comment: its ok, turns out same problem, removed = '' around keys